# Rails 3 Collection Select onchange Submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, submit, onchange

I'm trying to submit a remote form when the value of a Collection Select changes. I've tried:

```
"<%= form_tag ( { :controller => :images, :action => :index, :method => "post" }) do %>"

"<%= collection_select(:admin_image, :category_id, Admin::Category.all, :id, :name, {:onchange => remote_function(:url => {:controller => "/admin/admin_home", :action => "index"}, :with => "'category_id='+value")}) %>"

"<% end %>"
```

But I understand that remote_function is no longer in rails 3. So I've also tried:

```
{:onchange => "submit();"
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use Javacsript for this. If you're using jQuery, it's simple. You'll want to listen for the 'change' event and submit the form when it fires. I use this generic function and then tag forms I want to auto-submit on change with the "submit_on_change" class:

```
$("form.submit_on_change").each(function(idx,form){
  $(form).find("select,input").each(function(idx,element){
    $(element).change(function(){
      $(form).submit();
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

Make sure you run this after the dom loads, for example on document ready.

Answer (score 0):

After searching on the web, I found a better solution. Hope it helps....

"/admin/images", :action => "index" }) do %>
   "submit();" %>

Comment: could you please expand on this answer, and maybe reformat the code?