# Rails 4 - Javascript onchange issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Rails 4 - collection_select JS issue.

I am trying to get form to submit when a dropdown value is changed. Ive tried several different solutions, but the JS never fires for in my collection_select. I can get it to fire for an input without an issue, just not a collection_select.

Here is my current code

```
 <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select(:assign_eq, @users.all, :name, :name, :prompt => true, :prompt => 'Sort By Account Manager', :onchange => "this.form.submit()")%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select), you note that method signature requires a second hash:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:assign_eq, @users.all, :name, :name, {:prompt => 'Sort By Account Manager'}, :onchange => "this.form.submit()")%>
```

i.e. enclose prompt with braces, to denote the second hash which is meant to contain html options.

I also deleted one prompt option.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here to get on change event by writing a javascript/jQuery on form submit.

Reference: [Rails 3 Collection Select onchange Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370046/rails-3-collection-select-onchange-submit)

Under document ready:

```
$("form.submit_on_change").each(function(idx,form){
  $(form).find("select,input").each(function(idx,element){
    $(element).change(function(){
      $(form).submit();
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```